# ArrayExpression error when upgrade from 1.5.2.2 to 1.6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I have upgraded meteor from 1.5.2.2 to 1.6 and I have got the following message:

```
/home/mai/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.9.0.l8rb8s.l2n4++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/babel-types/lib/definitions/index.js:147:13:
   imports/ui/components/Public.js: Property elements[3] of ArrayExpression expected node to be of a type
   ["null","Expression","SpreadElement"] but instead got undefined
   at validate
   (/home/mai/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.9.0.l8rb8s.l2n4++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/babel-types/lib/definitions/index.js:147:13)
   at validator
   (/home/mai/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.9.0.l8rb8s.l2n4++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/babel-types/lib/definitions/index.js:57:7)
   at Object.validate
   (/home/mai/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.9.0.l8rb8s.l2n4++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/babel-types/lib/definitions/index.js:190:10)
   at validate
   (/home/mai/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.9.0.l8rb8s.l2n4++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/babel-types/lib/index.js:505:9)
   at Object.builder
...
...
```

I see the post in stackoverflow but I don't know how to apply or change my code:
[Babel: Replacing ArrowFunctionExpression vs FunctionDeclaration in ExportDefaultDeclaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39151261/babel-replacing-arrowfunctionexpression-vs-functiondeclaration-in-exportdefault)

The following is Public.js file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const Public = ({ loggingIn, authenticated, component, ...rest, match, history }) => (
    <Route
        {...rest}
            render={props => (
                !authenticated ?
                (React.createElement(component, { ...props, loggingIn, authenticated })) :
                (<Redirect to="/events" />)
        )}
    />
);

Public.propTypes = {
    loggingIn: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    authenticated: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    component: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    history: PropTypes.object,
    match: PropTypes.object,
};

export default Public;
```

Please help to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I use PUP from Cleverbeagle, and they have updated the code.
So I change the code and also it works with Meteor 1.6

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const Public = ({ loggingIn, authenticated, component, path, exact, ...rest }) => (
    <Route
        path= {path}
        exact={exact}
            render={props => (
                !authenticated ?
                (React.createElement(component, { ...props, ...rest, loggingIn, authenticated })) :
                (<Redirect to="/events" />)
        )}
    />
);

Public.propTypes = {
    loggingIn: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    authenticated: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    component: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default Public;
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this question was answered long time ago, but I had the same problem recently, after 40 minutes I found the solution: only need to set the spread object param as the last param.

In this case:

```js
const Public = ({ a, ...rest, b }) => (
    <div>fail</div>
);
```

to

```js
const Public = ({ a, b, ...rest }) => (
    <div>success</div>
);
```

This works for me